# Special char in url causes exception in daphne

Tags: django, unicode, daphne

On my local and the staging system one URL works with the special character (umlaut) but on our production system an exception is thrown: "Invalid characters in path - daphne" (https://github.com/django/daphne/blob/993efe62ce9e9c1cd64c81b6ee7dfa7b819482c7/daphne/http_protocol.py#L100)

I use nginx as a reverse proxy in front of daphne.

The staging system, as it should be, is basically the same as the production system, same nginx config and same daphne arguments etc. But I guess missed something. I do not know where else to look. The setup is: Django -> Daphne -> nginx -> AWS (ECS) -> EC2 Load Balancer.

I checked both nginx configs and they are the same, except for the domain name.

Update:

Anonymized URL: `https://app.****.com/api/****/abc-def-ab%C3%BCcdef`

The complete error message is: `400 Bad Request

Invalid characters in path
Daphne`

nginx log: `**** - [03/Jan/2024:12:52:26 +0000] "GET /api/***/****%C3%BC**** HTTP/1.1" 400 442 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:121.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/121.0"`

django/daphne log: `127.0.0.1:47596 - - [03/Jan/2024:12:52:26] "GET b'/****/****-****\xc3\xbc****'" 400 430`

This is the working response from the staging system:

nginx: `**** - [03/Jan/2024:12:56:22 +0000] "GET /****/****-%C3%BC**** HTTP/1.1" 200 269884 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:121.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/121.0"`

django/daphne: `127.0.0.1:47376 - - [03/Jan/2024:12:56:53] "GET /****/****-%C3%BC****" 200 835470`

And NOW I see a difference (production daphne `\xc3\xbc` vs staging daphne `%C3%BC`) - but why?

Comment: Can you share the URL (anonymizing the domain if needed) that is causing the issue and the traceback?

Comment: @IainShelvington sure! https://app.****.com/api/****/abc-def-ab%C3%BCcdef - I updated my question with the log messages.

Comment: *Unencoded* Unicode characters are not allowed in URLs. They **must** be percent-encoded

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, but as you can see in the nginx log files, they do not contain *unencoded* characters. And as both configs are the same, I wonder how this can happen.

Comment: The URL in `daphne.log` is not percent-encoded, hence invalid if that's how it's being sent over the wire

Comment: @RemyLebeau There is nothing between nginx and daphne. Both nginx configurations are the same. In the nginx log, both URLs are correctly encoded.